# Phonegap application throws error running Android ICS 4.0, but works fine on Android 2.3 and below

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a problem with PhoneGap mobile app running on Android. I am currently using PhoneGap version 1.3.0. And it works perfectly on Android 2.3 and all the lower versions of Android. However, when I try to run it on Android 4.0 - Ice cream sandwich it throws this dialog error:

```
Application error - A network error occurred. (file:///android_asset/www/index.html#)
```

In the logcat there is not much relevant info, only this:

```
chromium - Unknown chromium error: -6
```

Anybody has any idea why my app works fine on all Android versions except the newest 4.0 ICS ? 
Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: What is the url you are passing into super.loadUrl() in your main java class?

Comment: super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html#");

Comment: IIRC there is a bug in the 3.X versions of Android and it is probably in the 4.0 version as well. Try removing the # from your URL.

Comment: @SimonMacDonald Please add your comment as answer, because removing hash(#) from the end of the URL worked magically ! Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC there is a bug in the 3.X versions of Android and it is probably in the 4.0 version as well. Try removing the # from your URL and things should work for you.

Comment: > chromium - Unknown chromium error: -6 
means 404 
Probably because of the # - other parameters can cause Problems as well (?=...). Also the placement of the script tag within the body tag can cause Problems.